# Why the delete?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A diamond moderator deleted [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/71351/42320)

> **For some reason a number of people commented based on the assumption that Antifa is US-based. But it's simply not the case.** The "black block", as they are known for their attire of choice, has been protesting at WTO meetings for many years before most people in the US even knew who they were. They are an international movement. I won't call them an "organization" because I don't have any way of knowing who is behind the movement.

The reason given was

> ...This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question...

---

But my answer (above) builds up on another very popular [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/53652/42320) to the same question. Which states that

> Another problem, as also mentioned in other answers, is that there is no definition of **domestic terrorist groups** in the US:

as well as another [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/53650/42320) saying

> Currently, there is no official designation for **domestic terrorist groups**.

---

The moderator seems to have taken no effort to try to understand the answer that I wrote.  There was no comment asking for a clarification.  There was no downvote.  And the time between my posting the answer and the moderator deleting the answer was very short.

Are you just kicking the proverbial dog or is there something profound I am not getting?

Answer (score 6):

Well, you didn't answer the question. That's why I deleted it.

The question asks whether the US president has the power to label Antifa as a terrorist organization. Your answer seems to be a reply to other answers or comments rather than an answer to the question. It does not consider the president's powers at all. Instead you just focused on some unrelated matter* regarding Antifa.

* By unrelated matter I mean that it's not part of the question. It may be part of some answers or other comments but replying to that is really not what the answer box is for.

That's what I mentioned in my comment under your answer as well:

> Welcome to Politics! This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](//politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. See also: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//politics.stackexchange.com/tour)

See also [our help center page on answering](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Among other things, it says:

> ### Answer the question
>
> Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Comment: Right.  Moderator or not, it's probably best that other people make a judgement as to whether or not you are being heavy handed.  The answer builds on other questions which do mentions President's power wrt to non-US organizations.  But that is besides the point here.  Your deleting the question instead of attempting to take corrective measures is what is troubling.

Comment: @wrod Deleting answers that don't answer the question isn't "heavy-handed", at least, not by SE standards. It's standard operating procedure here. You have the opportunity to take corrective measures by editing the answer. I think what you were trying to get at (but didn't explicitly state) is that, since Antifa aren't based in the US, they're not a domestic terror group and therefore *can* be classified by the US as terrorists, contrary to the existing answers. If you can edit your answer to make that clearer, it should get undeleted.

Comment: @F1Krazy I did try to get at that.  My problem is that I don't know why that would be the case.  I can quote (or link) to the other answers which explain why that would be the case.  But if anyone asks me to clarify why it's ok for such a designation for a foreign group, I would not be able to answer that.  Ok.  I guess i'll try to work around with links.  Thanks!

Comment: @F1Krazy I did edit it.  And did edit it as you suggested.  And it hasn't been undeleted.

Comment: @wrod I've undeleted it because it now attempts to answer the question. I still think it lacks sources to provide a convincing argument though. It also doesn't really touch on the president's involvement in such decisions.

Comment: @wrod Sorry. I should have added that it wouldn't get undeleted automatically, and that you'd have to flag it to bring it to the moderators' attention. I've checked the edited, undeleted answer and it looks much better now.

Comment: @JJJ fair point. I added some links.